# No sound on music players, YouTube videos etc. Only get system sounds

Tags: sound

Sound is not working. I get system sounds but other sources like Rhythmbox don't work

Comment: Open `System Setting` from dash and click `Sound` icon. Then go to `Hardware` tab -> `Profile` try to change other profile. you can also test while running some media player. Try it once..

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as [Saurav Kumar](https://askubuntu.com/users/124963/saurav-kumar) mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344797/no-sound-on-music-players-and-youtube-etc-only-get-system-sounds#) Open **System Settings** from dash and click **Sound** Then go to **Hardware > Profile** and test other profiles that match your audio connections. You should test while running some media player.
If it will not work, then look at Ubuntu's page about sound problems: [Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) or better yet, the more recent [help wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems).